# 履歴やウォッチリストを実装する際、DBにはそれらのデータをどのように保存すれば良いのか

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework

通販サイトのカート、動画サイトのウォッチリストや履歴などは、
1ユーザーに対し、複数のデータ（カート内の商品,閲覧したページ）が結びつくかと思いますが、
それらはどのようにDBに保存し、取得すればいいのでしょうか？

配列で保存、と思ったりしましたがよろしくない気がしました（なんとなくですが...）

> 環境
>   -MySQL5.6
>   -Play framework2.3
>   -Scala2.11

Comment: Play frameworkを使ったDBアクセスの書き方ではなく、DBのテーブル設計に悩んでいるということでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist 
コメント有難うございます。
DBのテーブル設計についてです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

通販サイトに限った話になってしまいますが、[こちら](https://github.com/EC-CUBE/ec-cube/tree/eccube-3.0.0-beta/docs)でEC-CUBEのER図が公開されています。
日本では有名なECのプラットフォームだと思いますので参考にしてみては如何でしょうか。
※余計なお世話かもしれませんが、judeファイルは[astah* community](http://astah.change-vision.com/ja/product/astah-community.html)で開けます。

また、動画の閲覧履歴のような永続保存しなくてよさそうだったり、ACIDを強く意識する必要のない情報なら、[NoSQL](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)を検討してみても良いんじゃないかと思います。

Comment: コメント有難うございます！
見方があっているか自信ありませんが、履歴用のテーブルを作成しているみたいなので、はやり作ろうと思います。

有難うございます！

Answer (score 1):

つい最近でた "理論から学ぶデータベース実践入門"

http://gihyo.jp/book/2015/978-4-7741-7197-5

という本の第9章が「履歴データとうまく付き合う」となっているので、参考になるのではないかと思います。

今、手元にないので、記憶を元にすごく簡単に要約しておくと

- そもそもリレーショナルデータベースは履歴データを扱うものとして作られたわけではないので、完璧な方法は存在しない
- 扱おうとすると、いくつかの方法がある
- それぞれの方法はトレードオフなので、それらを理解して状況によってどれを使うか判断すべき
- DBのカラムにフラグを追加する方法は一見手軽だが、かなりデメリットが多いので避けるべき

という感じだったと思います

Comment: 、本題からそれてしまうのですが、上記の第9章が「履歴データとうまく付き合う」の"履歴データ”は、トランザクションデータという意味ではなくて、同一データの時系列上のある時点の集合としての履歴データ かと思います。つまり、テーブル A に キー a のレコードがあったとして、昨日時点の キー a のレコード(=a') と 今日時点のキー a のレコード (=a'') を、RDBMS 上で別の レコード として管理しようとするとツライ。という主旨だったと思います。

Comment: 質問と微妙に違うかもしれないことは認識してましたが、元の質問自体も「通販サイトのカート、動画サイトのウォッチリストや履歴」と、ある程度は曖昧だったので、それを承知のうえで、少しは参考になると思って書きました

Comment: 細かいことで失礼しました。書籍は参考になると思います！

Comment: コメント有難うございます！
ドンピシャな内容の参考本ですね。
チェックしてみます！